# Large Database Handling

Tags: mysql, mongodb, jdbc, database-design, database

Good evening.

So, I have to store information about different places. Each place has different information including a title, category and location. The problem is that I will have around 50 million places and i'll have to search them by title, category and location(which consist of street, country etc.).

I have installed MySql and mongoDB, but other alternatives are also accepted. Also, the server has only 2GB right now(it will be increased later - more RAM or maybe even a cluster...but later) and i'm not sure if it is enough. The HDD space should be more than enough.

Some of my ideas were to create tags for each place, and search by tags(tags will be the fields i use for search, and indexed), but i'm not sure if it is a good idea and how is it better to implement.

Are there any suggestions about how is it beter to implement it ? I will fill it only once with all information, and then use it only for searches.

P.S.: in the current test version i'm using the MySql database from JAVA, with JDBC(i though that it's faster than JPA solutions).

Comment: Can you give examples on the types of queries you want to run against your data?

Comment: I will just have to search by (title, category) and location. As search parameters i'll have 2 parameters: keyword(should be searched in title/category) and location(that can be just "London", or Durnham, NC, USA)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider 50 million rows mid-sized.  Certainly not "large", and well within the capability of either MySQL or Mongo DB to handle.

The choice of SQL (e.g. MySQL) vs. NoSQL (e.g. Mongo DB) should be driven by a wide set of considerations including performance requirements, query patterns, sharding requirements (Mongo DB is strong here) and the experience of the team.  There's quite a learning curve getting all of the operational tasks right for a database you are not familiar with.

The amount of RAM you must have is dictated by the working set... the number of records that are typically being accessed throughout the day.  If some records are accessed a lot (Los Angeles, CA) and others very infrequently (Los Banos, CA), you need less memory for good overall performance than if all records are accessed with equal likelihood.  Do performance measurements early enough in the process that you can plan for the amount of RAM you will need.

With geographic search, users will often supply incomplete information, or partially incorrect information, if you allow free-text input.  Tags will not really help with that.

If you present the location choices in a structured manner (e.g. drop-down menus) you can just use the primary key of the location as the "tag".

Comment: Yep, location is supplied as incomplete information, and this is why i though of tags....

Comment: I forgot to mention, that i'll have to fill the database with already entered information, so drop-down menus for validations doesn't work fine....but it could help with searching...